# Actively flagging & reviewing non-answers

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, closed-questions, asking-questions

Reviewing first posts, I've come across quite a few non-answers and even questions posted as answers. I realize we are still in beta but we should actively encourage users to post such "answers" as comments (when appropriate) and point them elsewhere when it's blatantly off-topic.

This community doesn't necessarily need to hold to the same standards as SO but certain basic standards should be moderated to ensure quality of the community.

Can we please be more active about addressing these sorts of answers in a *friendly* , welcoming way while also closing them when they don't belong here or are clearly not an answer?

Comment: Agreed! Thanks for your reviewing activities. If you find some, flag them. The mod team will go through them and remove them or convert them to a comment.

Comment: @TeeAttack42 Yes, I flag when appropriate.